# how to create dictionaries in c++?

Tags: c++

I'm practicing the map Library of c++, I'm trying to run this code, but I get the error: mmap does not name a type. here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<map>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;
class environment
{public:
    environment(){
    map<char,int> mymap;
    mymap.insert(pair<char, int>('A', rand()%1));
    mymap.insert(pair<char, int>('B', rand()%1));}
};
class vacuum public: environment
{
void print()
    {
    cout<<"printing the conditions of the rooms #0 indicate the room is clean and #1 indicate that the room is dirty "<<endl;
    cout<<"room1:"<<mymap.at('A');
    cout<<endl<<"room2: "<<mymap.at('B');
}
};
void main()
{
    vacuum o;
    o.print();
}
```

Comment: When posting a question, make sure to include the full error message

Comment: `mymap` is a variable local to the constructor. It is not a member of the class

Comment: `class vacuum public: environment` is a typo. You placed the colon in the wrong place should be `class vacuum : public environment`

Comment: Use `std::map` instead of `map`

Answer (score 2):

```
environment(){
map<char,int> mymap;
```

This declares this `mymap` as a ***local variable*** in the constructor. That's what it means when you declare something in a function or a class method, and a constructor is just a class member, for the purposes of this discussion.

This means that as soon as the constructor returns, this `mymap` disappears, gone forever. Your `vacuum` subclass's attempts to access this `mymap` will not be very successful.

It's obvious that your intent is to declare `mymap` as a class member, instead. Given that this needs to be accessible from the subclass, at the very least it needs to be a `protected` class member.

```
class environment {

protected:
    map<char,int> mymap;

public:
    environment(){
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @SamVashavchik answer, you also need your `print()` method in the `vacuum` class to be public. By default, methods in classes are private and without explicitly specifying as public, you will not be able to call it as you do now. In general, if you want everything to be public, you can just use a `struct` where everything is public unless stated otherwise.

Also, `main()` should return an `int`, which causes an error on my system (Linux). And finally, it should be `class vacuum: public environment` rather than what you have now.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the working example(according to the code you gave). Note the `mymap` is made to be a data member instead of a local variable.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<map>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;
class environment
{   public:
  map<char,int> mymap;  //now mymap is a data member instead of a local variable and can be accessed by users of the class 
 environment(){
   
    mymap.insert(pair<char, int>('A', rand()%1));
    mymap.insert(pair<char, int>('B', rand()%1));}
};
class vacuum :public environment
{
public://note that now the print member function is public
void print()
    {
    cout<<"printing the conditions of the rooms #0 indicate the room is clean and #1 indicate that the room is dirty "<<endl;
    cout<<"room1:"<<mymap.at('A');
    cout<<endl<<"room2: "<<mymap.at('B');
}
};
int main()
{
    vacuum o;
    o.print();
    return 0;
}
```